# Given a prime number a of the form 29 (mod 40) or 40k + 29. Show that the prime a cannot divide any integer of the form n^2 + 10.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, quadratic-residues, primitive-roots

Not sure how to approach this problem. First idea was proof by contradiction. Assume a divides n^2 + 10 and proceed from there. I couldn't reach a substantial conclusion from this approach.

Comment: This would appear to be a question about [Quadratic Reciprocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_reciprocity).

Comment: @lulu, I wonder whether there is an elementary solution that does not use QR.

Comment: @lhf Yes, I'd like to see that too

Answer (score 1):

$a\mid n^2+10$ for some $n$ is equivalent to $-10$ being a quadratic residue modulo $a$. Now
$$\left(\frac{-10}a\right)=\left(\frac{-1}a\right)\left(\frac{2}a\right)\left(\frac{5}a\right)$$
and if $a\equiv29\bmod40$ the following hold true (check e.g. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_symbol#Properties_of_the_Legendre_symbol) for confirmation):
$$\left(\frac{-1}a\right)=+1\qquad\left(\frac2a\right)=-1\qquad\left(\frac5a\right)=+1$$
Thus $\left(\frac{-10}a\right)=-1$, i.e. $-10$ is not a quadratic residue modulo $a$, and the question claim follows.